# center content of linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a linkbutton inside a div. I have set the height & width of the div to look like a square using css. I have also set height & width of linkButton via css. Also my LinkButto
display propery is set to block.(To get the hyperlink effect all over the control).
what I want now is to center the LinkButton text vertically and horizontally.

I tried all possible properties of div and linkbutton with no luck.
Only way I could do this was setting padding(top, left, right) but then it messes up the layout.

```
 .divblock
 {
     background-color :#EEEEEE;
     border:2px solid;
     width : 90px;
     height :80px; 
 }

 .Linkbutton
 {
     text-decoration: none ;
     color :black  !important;
     display:block;
     width : 85px;
     height :80px;
}
```

aspx:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">

            <asp:DataList ID="dl1"  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"      ItemStyle-CssClass ="Items"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    **<div class ="divblock">**
                    <asp:LinkButton **CssClass="Linkbutton"** OnCommand="PresItems_Command"     ID="TestLB1" runat="server" Text="Test" />
                   </div> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Comment: does text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdqu8/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="divblock">
  <a href="" class="linkbutton">Lorem ipsum.</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divblock {
     //other styles

     display: table;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .linkbutton {
     //other styles

     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```