# How to make an image take up an entire div height and width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following header element defined:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <h3 class="heading">Heading info here</h3>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs header-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this style:

```
.header-image {
    background-image: url("../img/email.jpg");
}
```

but the image isn't taking up the whole of the div, in fact, when I look at it in Chrome Inspector it has a height of 1px and a width of 380px

How do I make it take up the whole width and height of the div without padding or margins?

Comment: make sure ```.header-image``` has some height. and then apply ```background-size``` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use the `background-size` property (however, keep in mind this is not supported in versions of IE less than 9):

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

This will fill the width and height of the `div`, but will only be visible if the `div` has its own width and height as well:

```
.header-image {
    width: /* your width */;
    height: /* your height */;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire area to be covered while maintaining the original aspect ratio, you should use:

background-size: cover;

If you want the whole image fit in the div and you donc care about the image aspect ratio, use what @josh told you

background-size: 100% 100%;

But, it sounds like your div header does not bear the right height anyway. You have to make sure the height is what you want. Look at the rules in chrome inspector to find why it only has 1px. As a hack you might want to add height:200px; or whatever height fits you need in your .header class.

Answer (score -1):

try setting the display property of image

```
.header-image {
background-image: url("../img/email.jpg");
display:table-cell;
}
```

for the dive

```
<div "style=display:table; text-align:center" class="col-md-4 hidden-xs header-image"></div>
```

[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842286/center-content-of-linkbutton)